# Dark background behind UINavigationBar in push transition from UICollectionViewController with iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uicollectionview

I'm having a little problem when trying to go to the next UIViewController from a UICollectionViewController. The problem is: While the next view is pushed, a black background seems to be added behind the right side of the navigation bar. I tried to replace the next view controller but the problem is still there. But when replacing the UICollectionViewController with another one, the problem vanishes.

Note: this problem seems to be an iOS 7.1 bug. Because i don't remember that it happened before I updated my devices.

Here is a [Video](http://tinypic.com/r/2a7vt4i/8) of my problem if you didn't understand me

Anyone can help ?

Thank you all in advance and sorry for my english,

Bader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i finally knew what caused this problem. That was because i added an [ILTranslucentView](https://github.com/ivoleko/ILTranslucentView) as a subview of a UICollectionView cell. Also, using a UIToolbar instead causes the same issue ( i still believe this is an iOS 7.1 bug because this wasn't happening before ).

Solution: remove any UIToolbar from your view controller.

Answer (score 11):

Setting `self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor` to the color you want will solve this problem.

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem.
It's a bug.
UINavigationController view has a black background, and it spoils translucent Navigation Bar at transition time.
To resolve this issue, you should change background of UINavigationController in code by this way:
`self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

Or set view color of UINavigationController in Interface Builder:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

While the next view is pushed, in that view controller’s .m file remove self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone; if you wrote in your code.

Comment: i didn't write that. and it's not because of the next (pushed) view controller, because i've already replaced it with another one and the problem still exists.

Answer (score -1):

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO`